# How to update beg end with comment-region

Tags: ess, comment

Scenario: I have *Emacs* open with split window. Top window contains an *R* script. Bottom windows has the interactive *R* session.  I want to be able to copy a region from the interactive window to the script window, AND have the copied region be commented.

My current approach (below) does this to the region:

1. `comment-region`
2. copy to other window/buffer
3. `uncomment-region`

My problem is that `comment-region` does not update beg/end. This causes the copy to other window to not copy the entire commented region (since the commented region is now larger).

How do I get comment-region to update beg/end ?

```el
(defun duplicate-region-to-other-window-and-comment (beg end)
  "Duplicate the region to other window. Comment it."
  (interactive "r")
  (comment-region beg end)
  (pcase (window-list)
    (`(,w0 ,w1)
     (with-selected-window w1
       (insert-buffer-substring (window-buffer w0) beg end)))
    (_ (user-error "Only works with 2 windows"))) ;; _ is really t
  (uncomment-region beg end ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid this problem by commenting the text after you insert it:

```lisp
(defun duplicate-region-to-other-window-and-comment (beg end)
  "Duplicate the region to other window. Comment it."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((text (buffer-substring beg end))) ;; collect text to copy
    (pcase (window-list)
      (`(,w0 ,w1)
       (with-selected-window w1
         (let ((start (point))) ;; store beginning of inserted text
           (insert text)
           (comment-region start (point))))) ;; comment inserted region
      (_ (user-error "Only works with 2 windows")))))
```

Comment: Please reformat (reindent) your code. It looks like it might a result of copying TAB chars. (Before copying, `M-x untabify` is your friend.)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.